# How to fix responsive image display with inherited padding

Tags: html, css

I am modifying a joomla virtuemart template. I have added the banner image in a custom code block that I have placed in an existing module position. As such it has inherited some css properties around it that appear to be giving it padding. My banner should display the full width of the top menu bar (you can see it here: https://www.artisanbelle.com). I don't know how to remove the padding and fix the display. It has displayed the correct image, which is 1920px wide and when I had this same image displayed in the pre-existing slider, it fitted across the menu bar fine.

The code I have tried is below. Also this is the first time I am using srcset and sizes, so if I am doing anything wrong there, please let me know.

```
  <div class='illustrationz'>
    <img src='https://www.artisanbelle.com/images/stories/mainlg.jpg'
         srcset='https://www.artisanbelle.com/images/stories/mainxsm.jpg 600w,
         https://www.artisanbelle.com/images/stories/mainsm.jpg 960w,
         https://www.artisanbelle.com/images/stories/mainmd.jpg 1280w,
                 https://www.artisanbelle.com/images/stories/mainlg.jpg 1920w'
         sizes='(min-width: 600px) 960px, (min-width: 960px) 1280px, (min-width: 1280px) 1920px, 100vw'/>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
.illustrationz img {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

.sectionz {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.headerz {
  height: auto;
  justify-content: inherit;
  align-items: inherit;
}
```

And this is the code that the template is wrapping this section in:

```
<div class="mod-slider-cont">
<div class="container">
<div class="inner-container">
<div class="custom"
```

And the template css that goes with it. I'm having trouble finding mod-slider-cont:

```
.vpf-topbar .inner-container {
    border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
    padding: 5px 0;
    margin-bottom: -1px;
}

#vpf-header .navbar .container .inner-container {
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    margin-bottom: -1px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a bit of a formatting issue here, you could use this as a fix:

```
.illustrationz img {
   width: 100vw;  // Use viewport width here instead.
   display: block;
 }
```

Although I've seen it used like this, the sizes attribute is typically only used it `rel=icon` and you'd be better off using css media queries for this.